# Feed refreshes on every "scroll"

Tags: bug, android-app

The feed does an update for every scroll, up or down.

It's like the logic for pull-to-refresh is fired constantly.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G930F

  - OS Version: 8.0.0 (G930FXXU2ERH1)